# Vue distribution files

Tags: vue.js

Vue’s documentation refers to 8 different Vue distribution files: vue.js, vue.common.js, vue.esm.js, vue.runtime.js, vue.runtime.common.js, vue.runtime.esm.js, vue.min.js, vue.runtime.min.js.

Nevertheless, when installing Vue we find a 9ª one: vue.esm.browser.js.

Any one knows what's the use for that one? Goggling tells me nothing.

Answer (score -1):

It is Vue but as an ES Module: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/12/04/webpack-intro-vue-js/